# How to get the number/count of user with exactly one order in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on a `Symfony 2.8` based project that allows an `user` to place an `order`.

Now I would like to create a `Doctrine` query that returns the number of `users` which exactly one `order`. I thought this would be easy but I am on this for hours...

1. Select the users and their number of orders
2. Select all users with `order_count = 1` from the result of step 1
3. Apply some more filters by selecting only orders from users in the result of step 2 and by adding condition (e.g. status = completed)

In SQL the following works fine to solve Step 1:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM order WHERE status = 'completed' GROUP BY user_id
```

However when I try to translate this to `Doctrine` I get the following error:

```
$qb->select('o_inner.user, COUNT(*) as count')
    ->from('MyBundle:Order', 'o_inner')
    ->where('o_inner.status = :status')
    ->groupBy('o_inner.user')
    ->setParameter('status', 'completed');

[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                              
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 30: Error: Expected Literal, got '*'
```

So I cannot even solve the first step. Any idea how to do this?

**EDIT:**

Did some more experiments with different selects:

```
$qb->select('o_inner.user, COUNT(o_inner.user) as count')
$qb->select('COUNT(o_inner.user) as count')

==> [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                             
    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 39 near 'FROM MyBundle:Order': Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined.


$qb->select('COUNT(o_inner.user)')
==> Works fine. So the "as count" statement seems to be a problem


$qb->select('o_inner.user')
==> [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                                           
    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'user FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

$qb->select('o_inner')
==> Workes fine

$qb->select('o_inner, COUNT(o_inner.user)')
==> Workes fine
```

So `$qb->select('o_inner, COUNT(o_inner.user)')` seems to work for Step 1. But since I cannot use a custom alias (`... as count` does not work), how can I reference the count result in a an outer select?

Comment: Try count(o_inner.user) or count(o_inner.id), it expects a literal. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ORM so you need to specify which field you want to count for example:

```
$qb->select('o_inner.user, COUNT(o_inner.user) as count')
    ->from('MyBundle:Order', 'o_inner')
    ->where('o_inner.status = :status')
    ->groupBy('o_inner.user')
    ->setParameter('status', 'completed');
;
$tags = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use ORM for complicated queries like reports/statistics.

Single optimized SQL query might have better performance and be easier to understand and maintain.